# Como remover ou limpar valor do input file?

Tags: javascript, arquivo

Oi pessoal do stackoverflow.

É possível remover ou limpar valor do input file ?

Também vi outro exemplo de resetar ou remover todos arquivos input file usando:

```
document.getElementById("seu_id_do_input").value = "";
```

Qual é melhor maneira de limpar input file ?

Alguma idéia brilhante ?

Comment: Não é possivel apagar arquivos no disco com JavaScript no lado do cliente. Precisas de fazer isso no lado do servidor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exemplo de como limpar o valor de um input type=file (na verdade é um truque):

```js
$().ready(function() {
 list = $("[class^=f_clear_]");
 if (list.length > 0) {
  $.each (list, function(key, row) {
   var arr = row.className.split("_");
   var selector = "#f"+arr[2];
   $(this).click(function(){
    GenericInputFileCleaner(selector);
   });
  });
 }
});

function GenericInputFileCleaner(selector){
 var clone = $(selector).clone(true);
 clone.insertAfter(selector);
 $(selector).remove();
 clone.attr("id", selector.substring(1));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="tmp.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="button" value="x" class="f_clear_1"> <input name="f[]" type="file" id="f1"><br>
<input type="button" value="x" class="f_clear_2"> <input name="f[]" type="file" id="f2"><br>
<input type="button" value="x" class="f_clear_3"> <input name="f[]" type="file" id="f3"><br>
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

A lógica aqui é clonar o elemento que deseja limpar, adicionar o clone logo na frente e remover original em seguida. Assim, o clone apresentará o atributo `value` vazio. No final, o clone recebe o mesmo ID do original. Mas isso deve ser feito após o original ter sido removido.

Isso é um meio mais simples e seguro do que tentar setar o atributo `value`:

```
document.getElementById("seu_id_do_input").value = "";
```

ou Jquery

```
$("#seu_id_do_input").val("");
```

Ambos deveriam funcionar bem, mas dependendo do browser e versão, podem não funcionar. O motivo todos já devem saber que é evitar manipular o atributo `value` com dados maliciosos. Porém, não há problema algum em apagar o atributo e todos os browsers poderiam liberar isso. Mas alguns browsers, talvez por bug ou falta de implementação, não permitem modificar nada, mesmo apagar o valor.

Por isso, uma opção mais segura é clonar, adicionar o clone no corpo HTML e remover o original.

Preferi fazer com JQuery por ser mais prático. O código ficaria maior e mais suscetível a erros de compatibilidade se tentasse inventar algo sem o auxílio do framework.

Achei desnecessário comentar o código e explicar em detalhes porque é bem pequeno, legível, fácil de entender. A parte que interessa é a função `GenericInputFileCleaner()`. O restante é meramente didático. Adapte conforme o seu caso.

A desvantagem é que obviamente perderá quaisquer eventos ligados a esse elemento ou que dependam do mesmo (`onclick`, por exemplo). Mas pode ser "facilmente" resolvido recriando tais eventos caso existam.