# Como limpar input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, formulário, input

OBS.: Tipos url e number principalmente mas se quiser colocar dos outros tb sem problemas)

De preferência em Js puro!

Já tentei coisas como this.value''; e não resolveram!

OBS 2 : Já li o [Como remover ou limpar valor do input file?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168440/como-remover-ou-limpar-valor-do-input-file) e este não tinha resolvido meu problema, está falando sobre input file e usa um truque para resolver. Tentei adaptá-lo para o meu código e não resolveu!

Comment: A pergunta ficou pouco clara após a observação 2 @GiancarloSolderagrazino. Poderia fornecer os trechos relevantes do seu código e/ou algum exemplo?

Comment: Tenta editar seu post com seu código js, para nós entender o seu problema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depende do evento que vai invocar, mas basicamente vai funcionar para a maioria dos `input`.

### Javascript

Com *javascript* é possível mudando o valor da propriedade [value](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp):

```js
document.getElementById("limpar").addEventListener("click", function() {
  clearInputUrlNumberText("entrada");
});

function clearInputUrlNumberText(name) {
  var entradas = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='"+name+"']");
  [].map.call(entradas, entrada => entrada.value = '');
}
```

```html
<input name="entrada" type="url">
<input name="entrada" type="number">
<input name="entrada" type="text">
<br>
<button id="limpar">Limpar</button>
```

### jQuery:

Com jQuery é possível usando o método [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  $("input[data-name='entrada']").val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input data-name="entrada" type="url">
<input data-name="entrada" type="number">
<input data-name="entrada" type="text">
<br>
<button id="limpar">Limpar</button>
```

Comment: Acho que seria melhor uma solução usando jQuery, já que ele adicionou essa tag e provavelmente utiliza essa lib.

Comment: Ele enfatizou js puro, mas de qualquer forma é boa a dica. Obrigado @mauhumor

Comment: muito legal a sua maneira de trabalhar com `javascript` +1

Comment: Tem como fazer com que o name seja passado por parâmetro numa função? Olha minha tentativa: function clearInputUrlNumberText(){
var entradas = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='entrada3']");
[].map.call(entradas, entrada => entrada.value = '');
}

Comment: Tem sim @GiancarloSolderagrazino. Editei com o exemplo da sua tentativa, veja se é isso.

Comment: salvou meu dia! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Fico feliz em ajudar! Pode marcar a resposta como aceita se quiser @GiancarloSolderagrazino :)

Comment: Não tinha reparado que o cara pediu em JS puro. Então ignorem meu comentário.